# Eliminar un valor de una clase o JSON js

Tags: javascript, json

Estoy trabajando en un sistema muy basico de carga de facturas de compra y gestion de stock, pero hay muchos datos que no son importantes como para meter en la base de datos ya que no tienen otra funcion mas que ser solamente escritos en una tabla donde se guardan dichas facturas. Como por ejemplo los metodos de pago. Pero esos datos deben mostrarse al usuario a nivel de interfaz a la hora de la carga de datos.

Solamente para experimientar, cree una clase M_payment donde tengo todos los metodos de pago que utilzia esa organización con un par de funciones para obtener los datos, setear datos y ahora estoy viendo de eliminar uno de esos datos.

El problema esta en que cuando inicializo ese ARRAY de datos en el constructor, por mas que elimine todo el ARRAY se carga como estaba antes, y es obvio y natural que pase si los declaro cada vez que se instancia esa clase.

Entonces pense que cuando hago el constructor, deberia obtener esos datos de algun fichero y yo editar ese fichero cuando se modifique y colocar esos datos en el constructor. Pero esoty en el mismo problema porque no se si existe alguna forma de eliminar un elemento en un JSON por ejemplo y guardar ese cambio en el archivo.

```
class M_payment {
_payments;
constructor(){
    this._payments = [
        {name:"Cheque Tercero"},
        {name:"Cheque + Transf"},
        {name:"Credito"},
        {name:"Cuenta Corriente"},
        {name:"Débito"},
        {name:"Echeq"},
        {name:"Efectivo"},
        {name:"Financiación TGR"},
        {name:"Pagar"},
        {name:"Rapipago"},
        {name:"Saldo U$S"},
        {name:"Transferencia"}
      
    ]
}

get payment(){
    return this._payments
}

set payment(new_p){
    this._payments.push(new_p)
}
```

}

Elimine algunos datos para no hacer tan largo el ejemplo de datos que tengo.

Resumen:

Basicamente necesito saber como podría asignar el valor a _payments en el constructor para cuando el usuario quiera modificar los datos existentes se "guarde" dicho cambio para siempre || la forma de poder hacer un "CRUD" a un archivo JSON

Comment: Aun no entiendo muy bien porque no quieres usar una base de datos... pero si digamos es para pruebas, podrías usar el localStorage para almacenar ese array, y cada vez que se modifique actualizas el valor en el local storage, y cuando recargues la página lo inicializas desde el localStorage si es que tiene algo.

Comment: Las razones por lo que no quiero crear una tabla de metodos de pago (por ejemplo) es porque son solo datos de lectura que no van a tener casi modificación. Cada vez que se cargue una pagina donde el usuario deba interactuar con esos datos deberia hacer una consulta junto con muchas otras. Es para buscar optimización evitando hacer consultas de datos casi estaticos. 

Y digo casi estaticos porque si existe una pequeña posibilidad de que el usuario quiera agregar, eliminar o modificar una cada tanto. 

Con el localstorage persisten los cambios cuando se cierra la sesion o la pagina?

Comment: Pero no es que no quiera usar una base de datos. Si voy a utilizar una para guardar datos importantes como justamente esos datos de facturación que ingresa el usuario los voy a guardar en una tabla relacional.

Comment: Si, en el localstorage persisten en el navegador así se cierre la pestaña o ventana